# How to check SQL Server Reporting Services configuration status?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, registry, sql-server-2012

I am writing an installation automation program for SQL Server, while upgrading default instance `MSSQLSERVER` of SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2012, I need to check Reporting Services Configuration status.

Using registry there is possibility to check whether the Reporting Service is instaleld. But I am not getting any clue to check the configuration status of Reporting Services.

Please let me know, if you have any idea on how to check the Configuration Status of Reporting Services.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the Report Server Service is running in services.msc

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178811%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) link may help you.